# implicit and explicit solution for differentials

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

find implicit,explicit solution for the following initial value problem

$\frac {dy}{dx}=1-2y,y(0)=\frac {5}{2}$

find solution

$\rightarrow \frac{dy}{1-2y}=dx $

integrate both sides

$\rightarrow \int\frac{dy}{1-2y}=\int dx $

get

$\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}ln|1-2y|=x+C$

$\rightarrow ln|1-2y|=-2x+C$ (2C replaced with C)

exponentiate both sides

$\rightarrow 1-2y=e^{-2x+C}$

$\rightarrow y=\frac{1-e^{-2x}C}{2}$ (e^C replaced with C)

for $y(0)=\frac{5}{2}$,  C = -4

Do  I answered the question correctly or any of the step gone wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything looks more or less correct. If you trace the evolution of the constant in such detail, then you need to include a possible sign alteration in
$$
1-2y=\pm e^{-2x+C}
$$
where then $\pm e^C$ is replaced by an arbitrary real factor $C$.